# Uncaught TypeError: DB.find is not a function in React with Meteor 1.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, reactjs

I'm using Meteor 1.3 with React and I got this error. If I use the console in the browser everything works perfectly.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';

import ToolsForm from './ToolsForm.jsx';
import ToolsCards from './ToolsCards.jsx';


export default class Tools extends TrackerReact(Component) {

  constructor(){
         super();

         this.state = {
             subscriptions: {
                 tools: Meteor.subscribe('allTools')
             }
         }
     }

     componentWillUnmount() {
         this.state.subscriptions.tools.stop();  
     }

     tools() {
         return Tools.find().fetch();
     } 

  render() {

   return (
    <div>
     <ToolsForm /> <br/><br/>
     <ul className="resolutions">
                     {this.tools().map( (tool)=> {
                         return <ToolsCards key={tool._id} tool={tool} />
                     })}
                 </ul>
    </div>   
   ) 
  }
  
}
```

and I got this error message:

```js
   Uncaught TypeError: Tools.find is not a function tools @ Tools.jsx:25render @ Tools.jsx:35(anonymous function)
```

Comment: Tools is the name of your class, it does not have a find method on it, what did you name where you have your Tools?

Answer (score 0):

`Tools` is a React component in your code. `find` should be used on collections, not on React components. You'll need to define a `Meteor.Collection`.

See the example code here: https://github.com/ultimatejs/tracker-react

Comment: I got it now, thanks. My collection had the same name with the React component.